# Как передать Integer по ссылке

Tags: java

В главном потоке создаётся объект, в данном случае типа Integer. После этого создаётся побочный поток, который этот объект как-то меняет, на этом его работа заканчивается. И продолжается работа `main`, где просто выводим значение этого изменённого(как мы этого ожидаем) объекта. Но в результате вмето 10 получаем всё тот же 0, будто бы никаких изменений в побочном потоке и не было.
Но вот если этот Integer упаковать ещё во что-то, всё будет ок, и получим на выходе 10.

Подскажите, что я упускаю при работе с Integer?

```
public class Runner {

    static class ChangeInteger extends Thread{
        Integer i;

        public void run(){
            while(i < 10){
                System.out.println(i);
                increment();
            }
        }

        void setInteger(Integer value){
            i = value;
        }

        private void increment(){
            i++;
        }
    }


    public static void main(String[] args) {

        ChangeInteger CI = new ChangeInteger();

        Integer mainInt = 0;

        CI.setInteger(mainInt);
        CI.start();

        try {
            CI.join();
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        System.out.println(mainInt);
    }
}
```

Comment: А если запускать в том же потоке то что получится?

Comment: @RomanC да, об этом я как-то не подумал. Ну тогда вопрос не связанный с потоками, почему Integer так себя ведёт, он же вроде как объект должен рабоатть, то есть не копироватьсяпри передаче, или  что-то путаю?

Comment: В java начиная с версии 1.5 идёт автоматическое преобразование типов, до этого объекты вели себя  иначе.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`Integer` иммутабелен. Если вы хотите передать его по ссылке с возможностью изменения, то пишите свой врапер и передавайте его.

```
public class MyWrapInt{
    public int value;
}
```

Или используйте что-нибудь готовое, тот же [`AtomicInteger`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/atomic/AtomicInteger.html). У него есть метод [`set`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/atomic/AtomicInteger.html#set-int-) для изменения значения.

Comment: Пока писал, вы уже запостили то-же самое =)

Comment: @StrangerintheQ кто успел, тот и съел :P